# Cannot access internet from access point

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point

I am trying to turn an old router (henceforth "R2") into an access point to extend the WiFi coverage of the main router (henceforth "R1"). I:

1. Changed the IP on R2 to 192.168.1.2; R1's IP is 192.168.1.1.
2. Disabled DHCP in R2.
3. Rebooted R2.
4. Can access R2's web interface by connecting to R1 wirelessly or wired.
5. Can **not** access the internet by connecting to R2 wirelessly or wired.
6. Can access the internet by connecting to R1 wirelessly or wired.

I have also connected R1 and R2 via power line extenders, but tried connecting them directly with ethernet cables. No success either way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your second router connected to first one wired? Have you switched the second router mode from 'router' to AP? Is 192.168.1.2 out of lease?

Comment: What IP address, DNS and Default Gateway does your client get when connected to R2? Did you connect R2 to R1 via the switch ports (NOT the WAN/Internet port)? What did you try and what error do you get?

Comment: @Akina Wired (directly with ethernet cables or via power line extenders). I did not find a "mode" in the firmware web interface; just a box "enable DHCP" which I unchecked. What does "out of lease" mean in this context?

Comment: @StarCat Will check those later when home, but answering the other questions if it helps: neither R1 or R2 have WAN ports, but I did try many (all?) combinations of LAN ports between them, just in case. The "error" I get is that my pc will connect to the router but it says "no internet connection", and I can't access the internet.

Comment: If there is no regime in router's settings it can be used as a router only, not as AP... Now try to connect its LAN, not WAN, wire to primary router's LAN. And check its settings - if there is "isolated WiFi segment" or something similar in its settings - disable it. *What does "out of lease" mean in this context?* This means that primary router's DHCP scope do NOT includes this address.